# Setting command of WiFi enabled in not working

Tags: android

I created a timer which will check whether wifi is enabled or not (WiFiManager.isWifiEnabled()) and if it is not enabled then calling WiFiManager.setEnabled() method to enable device's WiFi, it starts timer in onCreate() method of Application's background service, timer will run every 1 seconds to verify wifi enabled or not.

When device is in active state,app runs properly but when device goes to sleep mode/locked state, wifi is getting disconnected even though I introduce timer to set wifi enabled in every 1 second. So not able to find out the way to keep wifi turned on even device goes to sleep/locked mode.

Comment: Do you use some kind of [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)?

Comment: I am using Android background service, so my application is having activities and one background service which will talk to server over WiFi but facing problem when phone goes to sleep mode as wifi got disconnected, I want to make Wifi turned on till my application running on the device, irrespective of device is in active of locked/sleep state.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that android will enter the sleep mode when the device is locked. this will put all services into the background.
i´m not sure if it is possible to lock the wifi connection. 
Mark Murphy created the [wakeful service](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) demo to show how to wake up services while the device is sleeping. maybe this could solve your problem but i´m not sure.